# FTPSVC setting itself to Disabled - Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, service

What would cause a service (FTPSVC) to disable itself?  I cannot find any group policy that would be setting this.  Looking at the event viewer for ID# 7040, I see it is being disabled by SYSTEM.  It appears to happen randomly and the only thing I can think is that the BeyondTrust Privilege Management that's installed is doing something.